# Read a power point template in R

Tags: r, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to read a power point template I already have, in order to avoid all the work in creating that formatting in R. (I'm still even looking for which package can do it: R2PPT, Displayr, OfficeR, ReporteRs (outdated), Q.)

The final goal, is creating a scatter plot chart (R gives its table as output) with the format already in the power point template. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you'd need to connect to the powerpoint object with `RDCOMClient` then look at the chart object, extract its attributes and build a `ggplot` theme that looks similar, not so easy and not sure if there's been any effort in this direction yet... Probably easier to define a few themes manually.

Comment: I have done exactly this with the package ReporteRs two years ago. So I guess it will also be possible with its sucessor officer. Indeed, [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/vignettes/powerpoint.html) vignette shows how to load a powerpoint and fill a placeholder with text or graphics.

Comment: with Markdown to PowerPoint. Add the pre-formatted presentation template to your premable ---
title: "Your Title"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---